# SEC TO-C filings - existing sites that compile these filings?

Tags: edgar

I am interested in certain companies' tender offer filings, usually made with SEC TO-C schedule forms.

Are there some already known sites that collate this information for free? If not I am thinking of implementing my own custon EDGAR scraper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sec-api (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sec-api) provides a websocket-based real-time API - works with server-side (eg Node.js) and client-side (eg React, React Native, Angular, Vue) JavaScript.

The API returns new filings in JSON format, eg:

```
{  
  companyName:            'WALT DISNEY CO/ (0001001039) (Issuer)',  
  cik:                    '0001001039',
  type:                   '4',  
  description:            'FORM 4',  
  linkToFilingDetails:    'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  linkToHtmlAnnouncement: 'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  linkToXbrl:             'https://www.sec.gov/...',  
  announcedAt:            '2018-12-21T20:02:07-05:00'
}
```

You can connect to the websocket channel, and just consider filings that match a given pattern.

The Node.js implementation seems to be very simple:

```
const api = require('sec-api')(); 
api.on('filing', filing => console.log(filing));
```

There seems to be a delay of 10 to 20 seconds between the filing publication time on sec.gov EDGAR and the "new filing" event trigger of the library.